# outline to only one side of div

Tags: css

I have tried few but is there a way to create an outline to right side of the div?
somthing like the purple line in the below image
https://unsee.cc/geduzopi/

Answer (score 2):

use a pseudo element absolutely positioned to the right of the parent, then use `translateX()` to push it outside of the parent.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  width: .5em;
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(200%);
```

```html
<div>1</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an `outline` on one side and **NOT** a `border`, you can use box-shadow with `inset` like I did in my codepen example below. My example is good to look at if you have a border radius.

https://codepen.io/drewkiimon/pen/qeWQVx

```css
div {
  background: pink;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use border-right. For example

```css
    border-right: aqua 2pt solid;
```

See
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-right.asp